# Creating a CSV file with proper columns & rows from json file using Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, json.net

Tried few commands like `Get-Content jsonfile.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json` but nothing worked.

How can I convert the name, version, id, author, description, deploymentDate into columns and new rows.

Json file example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "id": "f5e2b3ed-ac07",
    "customer": "Abby",
    "description": "An example- \n\nDate:\nFrom:\nTo:\nSubject:\nBody:\nAttachments\n\n\n",
    "deploymentDate": 11102021140122,
    "deployedBy": "Kathy Hick",
    "signDetails": {
      "signStatus": "notSigned",
      "signedBy": null,     
  },
  {
    "name": "This_is_example",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "id": "992e-da106ee7fcff",
    "publisher": "Customer",
    "description": "",
    "deploymentDate": 1634762732781,
    "deployedBy": "joehannible01",
    "signDetails": {
      "signStatus": "notSigned",
      "signedBy": null,     
  } 
  ]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Before we proceed you should urgently take the [Tour] and read at least the help topics for [Ask] and maybe [Mre] to set your expectations on SO. Regardless of that - when you post code or sample data you should format them as code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON data is invalid. If you use valid JSON it's only piping the JSON string to `ConvertFrom-Json` and piping this either to `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
$properties=@('Name','Version','Id','Publisher','description','deploymentDate','deployedBy')

(Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\testing.json -Raw  | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object -Property $properties | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content -Path C:\Temp\convertcsvtable.csv
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).